# SymbolicC++ error on linux

Tags: c++, linux, symbolicc++

I am trying to install SymbolicC++ from SymbolicC++3-3.35-ac.tar on Ubuntu 15.10.  I did a ./configure, make, sudo make install with no errors.

I tried to compile the following with `g++ test1.cpp -lsymbolicc++`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "symbolicc++.h" 
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  Symbolic x("x");
  cout << integrate(x+1, x) <<endl;       // => 1/2*x^(2)+x
  Symbolic y("y");
  cout << df(y, x) << endl;               // => 0
  cout << df(y[x], x) << endl;            // => df(y[x],x)
  cout << df(exp(cos(y[x])), x) << endl ; 
                             // => -sin(y[x])*df(y[x],x)*e^cos(y[x])
  return 0;
}
```

This code was from the Wikipedia article on SymbolicC++

I get the following errors:

```
doug@doug-Z170X-UD5:~/books_computerAlgebraSys$ g++ test1.cpp -lsymbolicc++
/usr/local/lib/libsymbolicc++.so: undefined reference to `Number<double>::Number(double const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libsymbolicc++.so: undefined reference to `Number<int>::Number(int const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: correction:  sudo make-install should be sudo make install

Comment: You can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35510776/edit) link to correct your question.

Comment: It looks like symbolicc++ is a header-only library. At least in my experiment your code builds OK without `-lsymbolicc++
`. The program crashes, probably because of a bug in the library, but that's another issue.

Comment: If I remove -lsymbolicc++ I get a lot of undefined errors

Comment: OK so there are two versions, a header-only version and a lib version. I'm getting the same errors as you with the lib version. It looks like a bug in the library.

Comment: @n.m.: With the header-only library, try to use the `-fno-elide-constructors` - it crashes for me as well without it, but not if I use this parameter to g++.

Comment: @axalis well, if you have to use -fno-elide-constructors, there is a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add "-fno-elide-constructors" to the g++ command line:

```
g++ test1.cpp -lsymbolicc++ -fno-elide-constructors
```

From the project main page http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html:

> Users of SymbolicC++ with GCC on 64-bit may need to use the -fno-elide-constructors flag.

**Edit**: But that seems to apply more to the header-only version of the library (there are two versions, header-only and the Autoconf library version). But I tried with your example and the AC library and for me it builds and works fine even without the "-fno-elide-constructors" (Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, g++ 4.8.4).

**Edit 2**: To wrap up, it seems that the library autoconf version does not work on every machine for some reason. With the header-only library, the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag needs to be used with 64-bit, and the `-I` option to point to the headers location (where the library is unpacked):

```
g++ test1.cpp -fno-elide-constructors -I<path_to_headers>
```

Comment: I get the same error:doug@doug-Z170X-UD5:~/books_computerAlgebraSys$ g++ test1.cpp    -lsymbolicc++ -fno-elide-constructors
/usr/local/lib/libsymbolicc++.so: undefined reference to `Number<double>::Number(double const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libsymbolicc++.so: undefined reference to `Number<int>::Number(int const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: What is your version of g++? (`g++ --version`) I just tried and I'm able to build the same version of libsymbolicc++ and the test cpp without any issue (but have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, g++ 4.8.4). Seems that the library might be already build wrong (when it reports the unresolved externals inside the *.so itself).

Comment: I have g++ 4.8.5.  I am using this version since the CUDA development system for my graphics cards requires it.  I have not had any problem with this version of g++.

Comment: ls -l of library:     -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4966984 Feb 19 09:01 libsymbolicc++.so.3.0.35*

Comment: What does output of `echo $CXXFLAGS` say on your machine? Btw interesting that mine is much smaller (size of 1071918).

Comment: echo $CXXFLAGS is blank.  I tried compiling the code on Debian 8.2  (g++ version 4.9.2) and got the same result.  I don't understand the header-only version  (which library does it use?).  I downloaded the header-only version but it was not clear how to use it, since there was no library.

Comment: With the header-only lib, you just need to point the g++ to the "include" folder of the library for the g++ to find it (`g++ -fno-elide-constructors -I<include_path> test.cpp`)

Comment: OK, that works.  The AC library version does not, for me.  Thank you for your help.  I am going to close this item.